# How to include language and other filters in Rtweet's search_fullarchive query?

Tags: r, twitter, tweets, rtweet

I want to include language filters in my Twitter premium search query in Rtweet's search_fullarchive. I'd like tweets for search query to be in hindi and English.

I have got this so far and it throws error

```
 tweet <- search_fullarchive("(#x or #Y or #z) lang: (en OR hi) place: India", n = 100, fromDate = "201911250000", toDate = "202001280000", env_name = "xxx", safedir = NULL, parse = TRUE, token = token)
```

Throws error for --> lang: (en OR hi)

How should I make it work?

Comment: I think you need to use `(lang:en OR lang:hi)` instead of the way you've got it here.

Comment: great, I'll add this as an answer, if you wouldn't mind marking it as correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `(lang:en OR lang:hi)` instead of the way you've got it here. The operator and query go together inside the parentheses.